# How to insert to mysql from multiple input fields with same name

Tags: laravel

So, for a few weeks now I'm learning Laravel framework and now I want to figure out how to in Laravel correctly submit form with all inserted fields with same name and how to save to database. So below is piece of code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('item') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="item"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" name="item[]" placeholder="Prekė">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('quantity') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="quantity"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Kiekis">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('price') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="price"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" placeholder="Kaina">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('item') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="item"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" name="item[]" placeholder="Prekė">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('quantity') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="quantity"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Kiekis">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('price') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="price"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[]" placeholder="Kaina">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Piece of Laravel code:

```
public function postNewOrder(Request $request)
{  
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'item' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    Order::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'total' => $request->input('total'),
    ]);

    Item::create([
        'order_id' => 1,
        'position' => 1,
        'item' => $request->input('item'),
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'sum' => $request->input('sum'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('order.list')->with('info', 'Užsakymas sėkmingai pridėtas');
}
```

I know that I need to loop with foreach, but I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for help in advance!

EDIT:
Here is example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xqy6qafk/3/

You click on "Pridėti prekę" button. One row is added to the table. So now I want to these 2 rows to be inserted into database with values when you click on button "Išsaugoti", but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you give a real example of what you have and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Edited my post. I hope you will understand me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're adding rows dynamically with jQuery, so I guess best way is to collect data from dynamically created rows with jQuery and then send this data to a controller.

In controller, if JSON data is prepared, you can just convert it to an array of arrays (array of rows) with `json_decode()` function.

After doing that you can insert multiple rows with single clause without any `foreach` loops:

```
Item::create($arrayOfArrays); // This will insert multiple items
```